# regex search and delete everything in brackets <>

Tags: regex, vim

Just learning vim and trying to delete everything between brackets `<>`. Tried `%s/<*>//g` but that just deletes the ending `>` bracket. I want to delete everything between and including the `<>` tags

Comment: Do you have a lot of brackets? Or just some?

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a modifier -- it doesn't match text by itself, it modifies the immediately previous thing to match zero or more times.  So your pattern will match zero or more `<` characters followed by a single `>` -- `>` or `<>` or `<<>` or `<<<<<<<<>`, but not if there's anything else between the `<>`.

To match any character, the special pattern `.` matches any single character.  So you could use `%s/<.*>/`, except that will cause problems if you have multiple tags on a line -- it will match the `<` of the first tag and the `>` of the last tag and delete them and everything in between.

Since tags can't be nested (you can't have a `>` or `<` inside a tag), you can get around this by using any "anything but" pattern:

```
%s/<[^>]*>//g
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I think Notepad++ also does not support lazy dot; I've gotten burned many times by this +1

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is

```
:%s/<.*>//g
```

But for this particular case, I would do

```
da<
```

after positioning the cursor inside `<>` as it involves lesser key stroke, `:help text-objects`